# Windows script to replace text in csv file

Tags: windows, script

I would like a windows script (without installation of external programs) to do the following:

```
read each line in a CSV file
if the line starts with ">r" then
  replace the 15th character with
    '0' if '8' 
    '1' if '9' 
    '2' if '0' 
    '3' if '1' 
    '4' if '2' 
    '5' if '3'
```

Is this possible? Any hints on what functions to use?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to this would be powershell as it's built into Windows since win 7.

Your problem seems to be relatively easy and straight forward.

On Windows 7 open your start menu, type *powershell* and launch powershell ISE.

Now you can start.

What you want to do:

1. Read csv
2. Check each line if condition is met
3. when condition is met, check which case is applicable
4. Repeat

   For #1 you can use the command (powershell term is cmdlet) `Get-Content`

For #2 you should use a `foreach` loop and the `if () {} else {}` functions

For #3 I would use the `switch ()` statement. Alternatively you can use the `elseif` function but that's not a good practice and adds a layer of complexity.

If you are stuck with commands you can utilize the `Get-Help` cmdlet. Or of course you can read through MS Technet articles [like this one.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849696.aspx)

Hope that helps.